# Integer parsing Bug in Java?

Tags: java, string, parsing, integer

I've been struggling with my code "behaving" really weird for the last two hours.

I'm working on a project using LibGdx.

What am I trying to do?

I read a text file and create a String array out of the lines of the file.
Now I want to take a line, replace a keyword inside it and parse the remaining String to an Integer.

```
String[] lines = data.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));    
int moves = Integer.parseInt(lines[11].replace("POSITION", ""));
```

but whenever I try to run the program on android it crashes just saying Fatal Exception.

The weird thing is that seemingly equal code works.

```
int moves = (int) Float.parseFloat(lines[11].replace("POSITION", ""));
int moves = Integer.parseInt(lines[11].replace("POSITION", "").substring(0, 1));
```

both of these get the job done no problem...

But why does the first (and most straight forward) code not work?

line[11] only holds "POSITION5"

This is the whole error I get in LogCat:

```
09-30 11:12:31.815 19016-19088/com.jradventure.game E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1154
                                                                      Process: 
com.jradventure.game, PID: 19016
                                                                              at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                              at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
                                                                              at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
                                                                              at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                                              at com.jradventure.game.Helper.LevelLoader.run(LevelLoader.java:98)
                                                                              at com.jradventure.game.Screens.LevelScreen.setupStage(LevelScreen.java:170)
                                                                              at com.jradventure.game.Screens.LevelScreen.<init>(LevelScreen.java:72)
                                                                              at com.jradventure.game.Screens.LevelSelectionScreen$1.run(LevelSelectionScreen.java:77)
                                                                              at com.jradventure.game.UIElements.SelectionButton$1.touchUp(SelectionButton.java:57)
```

This is driving me nuts! Please explain!

Comment: Have you printed out the value of `lines[11]`? What prints out?

Comment: print `String[] lines = data.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));  System.out.println ("[" + lines[11] + "]");  
int moves = Integer.parseInt(lines[11].replace("POSITION", ""));`

Comment: Why don't you assign the value of lines[11].replace("Position","") to a variable, debug and look at the value, then do the same thing with lines[11].replace("Position","").substring(0,10) you'll probably find what you are looking for.

Comment: I would guess that you have something in non-integer format, like `1.0`. Parsing it as a float works, and then you cast that to an int (with a possible loss of data, if the non-integer was something like `1.2`). Parsing it as an int doesn't work, since even something like `1.0` is not a valid int for Integer.parseInt (as specified in [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-)).

Comment: 'It crashes just saying Fatal Exception'. That's *your* useless error message. It would be more to the point to provide the actual stack trace. Edit it into your question.

Comment: I have tried printing line[11]. And I got "POSITION5", exactly what is written in the text document.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. You wrote:

```
line[11] only holds "POSITION5"
```

You coded:

```
Integer.parseInt(lines[11].replace("POSITION", "").substring(0, 10))
```

1. This removes `"POSITION"`.
2. At this point the string now contains `5`.
3. You then take a substring consisting of the first nine characters. But there is only one character in the string. If this doesn't throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` I will be very surprised.

Nothing to do with integer parsing whatsoever.

Remove either the `.substring(...)` part or the `.replace(...)`.

Comment: Confirmed that results in an out of bounds exception.

Comment: I am sorry! Of course it has to be :

`Integer.parseInt(lines[11].replace("POSITION", "").substring(0, 1))` Don´t know how the 0 got there. But the core of my question actually is why does this code work, while not writing substring(0, 1) results in a crash.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I found a solution to my problem.

I encountered even more weird interactions with the data i loaded from the text document. I was using

```
String data = Gdx.files.internal(path).readString();
```

To read the text file.

I replaced it with a buffered reader and everything works fine...

```
InputStream is = Gdx.files.internal(path).read();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line = in.readLine();
```

Maybe the `readString` method does some formatting that throws off android, I don´t know.

Thank you for your help!